# Load advanced jQuery version on page ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

- My page is loaded with jQuery 1.4.4
- On page ready I want to dynamically load jQuery 1.11.1
- My question is: There is a way to load advanced version of jQuery (1.11.1) with current jQuery (1.4.4)?

I've tried to use `jQuery.getScript()` in order to dynamically load JavaScript files and it worked fine, but the only file that didn't loaded is the jQuery 1.11.1 version

I know how can I do it with native JavaScript code, but I want a cross browser solution so it have to be with using of the current jQuery (1.4.4).

Answer (score 0):

You can use your version of jQuery independently via `jQuery.noConflict()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)).

Comment: Importing another version of jQuery will override the existing one, there's no need to use noConflict.

Comment: Right. But the question was "There is a way to load advanced version of jQuery (1.11.1) with current jQuery (1.4.4)?"

Comment: Yes, and as I said: importing the new version (1.11.1) over the old one (1.4.4) will override it. So there's no need of **`noConflict()`**. So your post doesn't answer the OP's question.